# In node.js Array.isArray = true, but array.length = undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have noticed that array do not return count of elements:

```
console.log('INFO : Condition: %s', JSON.stringify(entries[0].conditions))
console.log('INFO : Condition isArray - %s', Array.isArray(entries[0].conditions))
console.log('INFO : Condition cnt - %s', entries[0].conditions.lenght)
console.log('INFO : Condition[0]: %s', JSON.stringify(entries[0].conditions[0]))
var actionConditions = entries[0].conditions
console.log('INFO : Condition cnt - %s', actionConditions.lenght)
```

Console output:

```
[11:15:55.679] INFO : Condition: [{"type":"state","attribute":"below","entity":"wkor2Xf3h3GQ7vnj","value":"1200"}]
[11:15:55.680] INFO : Condition isArray - true
[11:15:55.681] INFO : Condition cnt - undefined
[11:15:55.682] INFO : Condition[0]: {"type":"state","attribute":"below","entity":"wkor2Xf3h3GQ7vnj","value":"1200"}
[11:15:55.683] INFO : Condition cnt - undefined
```

Could someone could point me to the problem/solution? Thx!

Comment: You have a typo. It should be length and not lenght

Comment: You should use a better IDE to spot simple typos like this. :)

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved.
You are right about IDE, in this case I was connected remotely and was using vi to edit code :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
console.log('INFO : Condition cnt - %s', entries[0].conditions.length)
//                                                                 ^^
```